# How can I declare 3 objects that have each other as an attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

everyone! I'm learning python and I ran into a problem while practicing. So, I have a class and three objects that belong to this class. Now I have something like this:

```py
class spam:
    def __init__(self, paramA, ParamB):
        self.paramA = paramA
        self.paramB = paramB
a = spam(c, b)
b = spam(a, c)
c = spam(b, a)
```

but when I run the code, I see three errors:
Undefined variable 'a', 
Undefined variable 'b', 
Undefined variable 'c'

I tried:

```py
a, b, c = spam(c, b), spam(a, c), c = spam(b, a)
```

but i still have the same error. How can i fix it?
Hope you'll help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it after creating them to access them all

```
class spam:
    def setParam(self, paramA, paramB):
        self.paramA = paramA
        self.paramB = paramB

a, b, c = spam(), spam(), spam()

a.setParam(b, c)
b.setParam(a, c)
c.setParam(a, b)
```